# C++ program won't compile when #include<stack> and #include<queue>

Tags: c++, macos, vim, utf-8

I'm using vim on Mac OS X, and my vimrc contains these keymappings:

```
function! CPPSET()
   set makeprg=if\ \[\ -f\ \"Makefile\"\ \];then\ make\ $*;else\ if\ \[\ -f\ \"makefile\"\ \];then\ make\ $*;else\ g++\ -std=gnu++0x\ -O2\ -g\ -Wall\ -Wextra\ -o\ %<\ %;fi;fi
set cindent
set nowrap
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :w<cr>:!g++ -O2 % -o %< -std=c++14 -I ./<cr>:!./%<<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> <F8> :w<cr>:!g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -O2 % -o %< -std=c++11 -I ./<cr>
endfunction
```

I'm using these keymappings to both compile and run when I press F9. It works fine until today: I notice that the file won't compile and give the following error when I include these headers:

```
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
```

I notice that when I remove two these headers from my cpp file, it works fine. Moreover, when I try to compile that file (with these two headers included) with

```
g++ hello.cpp (instead of using F9 in Vim)
```

It works just fine. Please take a look! I've tried reinstalling xcode, but it didn't work.

```
In file included from queue.cpp:16:
./queue:1:1: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000>
<U+0000><80><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0010><U+0000><U+0000>
<U+0000>p<U+0006><U+0000><U+0000><85>...

./queue:1:2: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000>
<U+0000><80><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0010><U+0000><U+0000>
<U+0000>p<U+0006><U+0000><U+0000><85>...


./queue:1:5: error: expected unqualified-id
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000>
<U+0000><80><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0010><U+0000><U+0000>
<U+0000>p<U+0006><U+0000><U+0000><85>...
            ^
./queue:1:6: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000>
<U+0000><80><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0010><U+0000><U+0000>
<U+0000>p<U+0006><U+0000><U+0000><85>...
                    ^
./queue:1:7: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000>
<U+0000><80><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0010><U+0000><U+0000>
<U+0000>p<U+0006><U+0000><U+0000><85>...

...continue
```

Edit:

- This is what Syntastic identifies: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbI0B.png)
- When I compile with g++ simply, it works seamlessly: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQvJ9.png)
- Comments out #include , #include  and Syntastic is satisfied:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGAmO.png)

Comment: You might have corrupted your GCC installation. Or you have a bugus `queue` file in your working directory. Your question is not clear enough. You should compile on the command line. Try to pass `-H` to `g++` to understand what files get included

Comment: The weird thing is that it compiles on the command line with g++...., but not with F9. Plus, Syntastic also notifies me about the error, while as far as I know, Syntastic use the system's compiler. Don't know what is happening.

Comment: No. I am not in front of your screen. You need to find out how you misconfigured something on your system. You probably won't get outside help (at least not without giving *a lot* more details). My recommendation is to compile on the command line, perhaps using some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like `make` or `ninja`. Then configure your source code editor to run that tool (e.g. to run `make`)

Comment: Try to add some `Makefile` in your working directory. It probably would solve your issue. Read [documentation of GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and how to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. Thank you so much.

Comment: But your title is incorrect. As you say, in a terminal, `g++` is able to compile a file with `#include <queue>`. But you messed up your IDE to the point that it is -indirectly- invoking `g++` with incorrect arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (according to your pictures) a binary file (probably an executable) named `queue` in your working directory. For some weird reason you need to discover, it gets included with `#include <queue>` (look into the actual program arguments passed to `g++` by your editor or IDE). Remove that file.

<sup>(as a rule of thumb, avoid naming your programs with the same name as *usual* things on your computer; having an executable named `queue` is bad taste for a C++ developer)</sup>

You might want to pass `-H` to `g++` to understand what files are included.

Then take several hours or days to read the documentation on [*Invoking GCC*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) and learn to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/). For `make`, read [documentation of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) then write your own [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) (caveat: <kbd>tab</kbd> characters are significant). For `ninja` see [this](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html). You need to understand how `g++` should be invoked.

At last, read the documentation of your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (or [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)) and configure it for your needs and tastes. You might want it to run some `make` or `ninja` command at a single function keypress. How to do that is explained in the documentation. For [vim](http://vim.org/), see [this](https://vim.sourceforge.io/docs.php).

The important thing to understand is that IDEs are just source code editors capable of running some *external* command to build your software. You can configure that command. C++ compilers are -practically speaking- always command line programs (usually [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)), and you need to learn how to invoke them (you generally should prefer to use a build automation tool to run your compilation commands).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I passed -H and I see it includes queue as you said. I remove -I in my mappings, and it works fine now. Do you suggest any books/guide that can walk me through on stuff like how compilers work, makefile,...?

Comment: I gave all necessary links to documentation. Just spend a few days reading it. BTW, you don't need to understand how compilers work *internally* (for that, start by reading [the Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)). You just need to understand how to invoke `g++`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Learn what RTFM means. It is tremendously useful